# Insert array to json with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a list of IP addresses taken from DB and I need to insert them to a json object as an array. 
This is the json:

```
$jsonString="{
        \"id\": 1,
        \"type\": \"service\",
        \"name\": \"\",
        \"msg_types\": [6,7,8,9],
        \"billing_id\": 1,
        \"billing_name\":  \"\",
        \"ips\": \"\",
        \"callback_url\": \"\"
    }";
    $CBjson = json_decode($jsonString);
    $CBjson->id = (int)$id;
    $CBjson->name = $name;
    $CBjson->billing_name = $billing;
    $CBjson->billing_id = (int)$guid;
    $CBjson->ips = (array)$ips;
    $CBjson->callback_url = $callback;
```

The list of IPs taken from the DB is a string, looking like this:
11.222.111.555, 11.222.111.148, 11.222.121.555
Now, I get:
`"ips": ["11.222.111.555, 11.222.111.148, 11.222.121.555"]`
Desired result is to have the list of IPs as an array in json:
`"ips":["11.222.111.555", "11.222.111.148", "11.222.121.555"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ipString = '11.222.111.555,11.222.111.148,  11.222.121.555 ';
```

Remove whitespaces to make it failsafe:

```
$ipString = preg_replace('/\s*/', '', $ipString);
```

Explode the string:

```
$ipArray = explode(',', $ipString);
```

Result:

```
array(3) {
    [0] "11.222.111.555"
    [1] "11.222.111.148"
    [2] "11.222.121.555"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do this:

```
$CBjson->ips = explode(", ", $ips);
```

Here you explode your string by a `,` delimiter. As a result you will have **array** with ip-values.

Comment: Thank you very much! @u_mulder